# Django User Model using AbstractBaseUser

Tags: django, django-models

So guys I am trying to implement custom user model in django. I have come across the problem where it Saying "no such column: UserAcc_mycustomuser.is_staff". I have tried reading Django Documentation but still not able to get it working

```
model.py

from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

from django.contrib.auth.models import (

    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)
USERNAME_REGEX = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]*$'

# Create your models here.
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
  def create_user(self, username, email, password= None):
      if not email:
         raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
      user = self.model(
           username = username,
           email = self.normalize_email(email)
      )
      user.set_password(password)
      user.save(using=self._db)
      return user

  def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
      user = self.create_user(
          username, email, password=password
      )
      user.is_admin= True
      user.is_staff= True

      user.save(using= self._db)
      return user


class MyCustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length= 30, validators = 
    [RegexValidator(regex = USERNAME_REGEX,message='Username must be alphanumeric or contain numbers', code='invalid_username')] , unique = True)

      email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique = True,
        verbose_name= 'Email_Address'
)
   is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)


objects = MyUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

Comment: have you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate?`.  `is_admin` is not actually a field in the default user model, it's called `is_superuser`. The `is_superuser` is used to determine privileges in the Django admin.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It needs to make and apply migrations to database

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```